# How to send parameters on O365 Power Automate HTTP Request connector

Tags: c#, httprequest, power-automate, asp.net-core-5.0, o365-flow

I've been troubleshooting this for days now but still no luck.
I'm trying to send parameters to an API link provided by Microsoft O365 Power Automate, this API requires a customer number, company code, and posting date and in return, **it will send me a table with the list of items that have the same customer number, company code, and posting date.** When I'm doing testing in Postman the sends status code 200, but when using VS and my code it always returns a status code 400.

**SoaController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string company, string customer, string asof)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        SoaParams soaParams = new SoaParams
        {
            Posting_Date = asof,
            Company_Code = company,   
            Customer_Number = customer 
        };

        var SoaJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(soaParams);   
        var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SoaJson);   
        var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer); 
        byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(SD.ApiUri);   
        var response = await client.PostAsync(SD.ApiUri, byteContent);  

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)   
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Success), Json(response)); 
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Failed), Json(response)); 
        }
    }
}
```

The below image shows that the parameters needed are correct.
[image]

[image]

But it's `SuccessStatusCode` always returns `false`

Comment: You are getting a Bad Request (400).  One of two things is happening 1) The default HTTP headers are different in c# from postman.  You may need to modify headers.  Often it is the UserAgent which specifies the type of browser (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) 2) You are failing the HTTP authentication which is done with TLS.  Either you are using http instead of https or using https when you should be using http.  Try add following to beginning of code : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: Hi @jdweng, I tried to add the code but it has the same output. I have check-in Postman and it has 23 headers. here is the test API link from O365 Power Automate https://prod-03.southeastasia.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/17b7217f3036421e857159c1a6d5f524/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=QOOJjkR2yxzN9eF-iakH6747MyLk8B8cfeP0juOoyo0

Comment: If postman is giving you headers than you are not using https which would show encrypted data.  Looks like you are sending a request with a body (contents).  When you send a request wit a body it is a POST.  You are missing the Post.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class

Comment: Yes @jdweng the test data has a body content.

Comment: My last link has two lines that are needed 1) request.Method = "POST"; 2) request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;   A request had three parts 1) URL and sometimes parameters after the question mark 2) HTTP Headers 3) Body.  Do you know difference between a header and body in postman?  Not sure if the 23 headers are really headers or part of body.  The Post and Content Length are Headers.

Comment: @jdweng hi.. I've checked the Postman.. it provided the C# code it uses. RestSharp. but still, no luck when I use it in .Net core

Comment: Are you using http or https (secure)?You could get a 400 either if you are sending http and the server want https.Or there is something wrong with one of the headers (or missing header).  I can't tell.Only way to determine which is occurring is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the Postman results with the c# results.  The TLS is performed before the Request is sent.  So first check with postmand and See if you get a TLS block.  And check what version of TLS is shown in sniffer.  Then try same with c# code.  I also need to know version of Net using to build and Target Net.

Answer (score 1):

I use a code provided by PostMan that look like this:

```
public List<BapiOpenItemDto> GetResponse(SoaParams soaParams, string uri)
        {
            var SoaJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(soaParams);
            var client = new RestClient(uri);
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddParameter("application/json", "[\r\n" + SoaJson + "\r\n]\r\n", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse<List<BapiOpenItemDto>> response = client.Execute<List<BapiOpenItemDto>>(request);
            return response.Data;
        }
```

and its working now.